# MS SQL Server 2005 - case insensitive password problem

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am checking for username and password for login in a procedure in MS SQL SERVER 2005. Since SQL Server 2005 is case insensitive even if user gives a lowercase password instead of a upper case one, the system allows to login.

What should I do?? Is there any command in Sql Server 2005 which can check the same??

Answer (score 3):

Use a case sensitive collation - e.g.

```
...where Password = @password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

and yes, you shouldn't really store plain text passwords in the database!

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER NEVER NEVER** store plain-text passwords!  Store a *hash* of the password and compare that.  You can use the [HashBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function.

Comment: @Rory - I'd never suggest md5-- HashBytes() supports a couple sha variants.  But this is still old now - it doesn't supporty bcrypt, and if you're not using bcrypt you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Yeah - it is v. old. I thought this answer was from Apr '10 not Apr '09. bcrypt all the way :-)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 is only by the default collation using case insensitive comparisons. You should not store passwords in plaintext. You should hash them with a reasonably secure hashing algorithm and store the hash. (perhaps you should really use a salt value as well but let's start with hashing).

Answer (score 0):

Use a case sensitive [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391(SQL.90).aspx) for the compare, for example:

```
SELECT
  Id
FROM
  UserTable
WHERE
  UserName = @UserName
  AND Password = @Password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```

Use a collation that matches the character set of the password column.

One a different note - are you sure you want to store *clear text passwords* in the database? This is well in the Top 5 of the Don'ts when it comes to security decisions.

Answer (score -2):

There are situations where you may want to store clear text passwords so I won't repeat the advice everybody else has, although it's usually sound.

Besides setting the collation, you can also use the varbinary trick like so:

```
WHERE
  CAST(Password as varbinary(20)) = CAST(@Password as varbinary(20)) AND
  CAST(Username as varbinary(20)) = CAST(@Username as varbinary(20))
```

The above will also result in a case sensitive search - just remember to set the varbinary length to the same as the field lengths.

To avoid index scans, you can include the case insensitive search as well - that'll make an index seek and the perform the varbinary search afterwards:

```
WHERE
  Password = @Password AND
  Username = @Username AND
  CAST(Password as varbinary(20)) = CAST(@Password as varbinary(20)) AND
  CAST(Username as varbinary(20)) = CAST(@Username as varbinary(20))
```

Comment: Can you give an example where it's valid to store a password as clear text? It would have to be in a system that I will never use, since there can be no valid example where I want you to know my password.

Comment: Interoperability with legacy systems for example. All I'm saying is that there may be reasons for one to want to store cleartext instead of hashing it - and I really see no reason for 10 answers all stating the same advice without offering a direct solution for what the OP is asking.